# Does the AppleTV had a place where I can see what's been downloaded to the device?

Tags: appletv

I've been looking through the user interface of the 2012 AppleTV and I can't find a place to see what has been downloaded to the device (e.g. movies or TV shows)--or the progress in-process downloads. I just purchased a season of a TV show and I want to see how many of the episodes have downloaded and to make sure they're downloading, without actually going to watch a show and see what the scrubber bar says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the latest versions of the AppleTV have 8GB of storage however the device doesn't allow the user to view or modify anything about the status storage (at least in a stock state).

During the introduction of the first all black AppleTV Steve Jobs said,

> People don't want to think about managing storage, they just want to watch movies and TV shows.